# Is big data suitable to frequent write data or frequently read data in terms of cost and performance?

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, nosql, cloud, bigdata

Is big data suitable to frequent write data or frequently read data in terms of cost and performance. I am talking about the datastore in GAE where write is a costly function and they also propose a hybrid solutions where sql and nosql can be used alnongside. So in such a structure what would you prefer to store in SQL and what in noSQL, distinguishing in terms of frequent reads and frequent writes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Google I/O 2012 - SQL vs NoSQL: Battle of the Backends](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rRoy6I4gKWU)

Comment: thanks for the link. but can you please summarize in 1,2 lines, Actually you tube is banned here in my country and I don't want to be seeing using proxy in my office

Comment: are you going to be using massive scaling and large amounts of data you read from much more then write? = noSQL.  Do you have lots of existing data or structures that you want to preseve in their relational form? SQL.

Answer (score 0):

"Big data" is an extremely broad term, and refers to a lot of things. The App Engine datastore, and other NoSQL databases, however, is optimized for reads that are far more frequent than writes, as is the case in most web applications.

Comment: ok so if we move on to the hybrid solution (merging SQL and NOSQL on GAE). we should consider the tables with more frequent writes (10-12 writes/sec) to the SQL database and frequent read tables to NOSQL ? Right?

Comment: @FaizanAli Possibly, but it really depends on what you're trying to do. I would be very reluctant to try and use two databases in the same app - you can almost certainly do what you need with the datastore alone.

Comment: well for 1 thing google recommends using the hybrid model, secondly, yes we can use the datastore alone and achieve all the functionality, but it has been proving too costly for our previous projects.

Comment: "Google recommends the hybrid model" well, no, again that depends on what you're trying to do. For most webapps, using the datastore alone will be faster and cheaper; SQL is mostly useful for OLAP. Again, it's impossible to provide such general recommendations - the best option depends entirely on what you're trying to achieve.